# Talend - Offline Package Installation

Tags: java, libraries, talend

I'm working on a machine which does not have access to the internet, and only has limited access to the other machines on our internal network.

I have successfully installed Talend 5.6 and when I attempt to create a new job a window pops up which says 'Missing third parties libraries'. It lists the two libraries found below:

- sqlexplorer.jar
- squirrel.jar

I have found the Talend [help page](https://help.talend.com/display/KB/How+to+install+external+modules+in+the+Talend+products) which very adequately describes how to install libraries while off-line, but I've been unsuccessful in figuring out where I can acquire the above mentioned packages. As you can imagine, a google search with the above package names has come up fruitless. The Talend application also appears to provide no hint or link to the source of these files (although it must be known, because this is an automated installation when connected to the internet).

Does anyone out there have a recommended way of finding this information, or happens to know who produces these libraries and where they may be found?

Thanks

Comment: You can use another computer to download the libraries, which will be placed in the studio folder under lib/java directory, or configuration/lib/Java hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution

- First you need to download the specified jar on internet.
- Go to talend and in the top menu : "Window > Show view > Talend > Modules"
- Click on the green arrow in the top right of modules view
- Find you jar in the list and import it with the 'jar drawing' button